# Create an image (bmp or so) from byte array containing 8bit(grayscale) or 1bit(binary) data in Java

Tags: java, image, binary, bufferedimage, grayscale

I have either a byte array containing grayscale data in 8 bit per pixel or containing binary data in 1 bit per pixel.

I tried this but its not working, i think its taking 4 bytes (32 bits) per pixel:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray));
ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", new File("filename.bmp"));
```

Can i change the type of the data to 1 bit or 8 bit in BufferedImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a slightly similar situation I used `Raster` with `BufferedImage`. See this simple example with gray scale 8 bit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(600, 400);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(200, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    WritableRaster wr = bi.getRaster();
    for (int col=0; col<bi.getWidth(); col++) {
        for (int row=0; row<bi.getHeight(); row++) {
            wr.setPixel(col, row, new int[] {(col+row)&0xff});
        }
    }
    JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
    f.getContentPane().add(l, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

I don't remember, whether `BufferedImage` supports 1 bit per pixel. You probably want to look at the `setPixels` variants which set many pixels at once.

Comment: Thank you, it works!
I used this:
`BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(picWidth, picHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
image.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, picWidth, picHeight, textureArray);`
textureArray being the byte array containing the gray values. I think you can use this too instead of the WritableRaster!